# Scrollable Background image cover for website with CSS

Tags: html, css

So I want a background image to be the whole page where the width fits the view though I scroll down to see the rest of the image, filling the entire body. The width is responsive though I can't get the image to scroll down. here is my css.

```
body { 
background: url(map.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-attachment: local; 
overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: You question is not very clear. Could you provide more details? such as screenshot.

In the meantime you could refer to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) example if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in firefox, I didn't try on other browsers

```
body{
    margin:0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('path/to/bg/img.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```